# Linking several separated Microdata <div>s together?

Tags: html5, microdata

I'm adding schema.org semantic markups, and would like to link several of which are in quite different parts of webpage together.

[This works](http://tinyurl.com/n4a8gvs) when I specify them as parent/child:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
  <span itemprop="distance">11 km</span>
  <div itemprop="event" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
      <span itemprop="name">first event</span>
      <span itemprop="startDate">2001-01-01</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, I don't know how to link them when they're separated by mountain of HTML:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
      <span itemprop="name">some event</span>
      <span itemprop="startDate">2002-02-02</span>
</div>

<!-- 
   ....
   zillion other HTML stuff
   ...
 -->

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
      <span itemprop="distance">22 km</span>
</div>
```

I guess I should use "itemref" or something to link related scopes, but I can't get it to work. Looking at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903781/marking-up-html-code-with-microdata-when-there-are-multiple-products-on-a-page) did't help in this case.

UPDATE: note that I'm specifically looking for solution that works via some kind of referencing and DOES NOT not work via nesting of any type. Also, ordering of second (non-working) example must stay the same (Event first, ExerciseAction second).
(There are several reasons for that outside of my control).

Specifically, "it works" is defined as at least [google rich snippets tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) showing that the items ARE linked together (as it does for that first working example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the `itemref` attribute.

From the [Microdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/) ([W3C Working Group Note](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/)) spec:

- [4.2 The basic syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#the-basic-syntax):

  > Properties that are not descendants of the element with the `itemscope` attribute can be associated with the item using the `itemref` attribute. This attribute takes a list of IDs of elements to crawl in addition to crawling the children of the element with the `itemscope` attribute.
- [5.2 Items: `itemref`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-microdata-20131029/#attr-itemref):

  > Elements with an `itemscope` attribute may have an `itemref` attribute specified, to give a list of additional elements to crawl to find the name-value pairs of the item.

---

**EDIT**: This should work according to the requirements that are mentioned in the question:

```html
<div itemprop="event" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" id="event001">
  <span itemprop="name">first event</span>
  <span itemprop="startDate">2001-01-01</span>
</div>

<!-- zillion other HTML stuff -->

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction" itemref="event001">
  <span itemprop="distance" id="entfernung">11 km</span>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2** (per [additional requirement](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52570/linking-several-separated-schema-org-divs-together/52592#comment52698_52592)): If a parent element specifies another item (e.g., a `WebPage` on the `body`), the above solution does not work because then the `event` property would also apply to the `WebPage`, which would not be correct.

There is no neat solution for this.

An ugly fix would be adding another item (with `itemscope`) but without any type (without `itemtype`) as parent of the `Event`. That way, the `event` property will apply to this untyped item, not the `WebPage`.

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

  <div itemscope> <!-- dummy item -->
    <div itemprop="event" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event" id="event001">
      <span itemprop="name">first event</span>
      <span itemprop="startDate">2001-01-01</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- zillion other HTML stuff -->

  <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction" itemref="event001">
    <span itemprop="distance" id="entfernung">11 km</span>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Could you give an example that would work given above ? I've tried for hours and didn't manage to get it to work (validating it on for example [google rich snippets tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets)). All I could do is make it include several other name=value pairs which were duplicated in another itemscope and had a same name - as mentioned in [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903781/marking-up-html-code-with-microdata-when-there-are-multiple-products-on-a-page); but I didn't manage to include another itemscope -- which is the question)

Comment: @MatijaNalis: I’ve added the snippet to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that was almost exactly what I was looking for! It does link them together as wanted in that simplified standalone HTML example. Unfortunately, [google rich snippets tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) throws an error at more complex example with "Error: Page contains property "event" which is not part of the schema." (whole page has more parent divs, the problematic one being for example http://schema.org/Webpage)

Comment: Any ideas how to fix that? Removing _itemprop="event"_ from schema.org/Event does not help, as it doesn't link itemscopes together then...

Comment: @MatijaNalis: I added another snippet, but this probably doesn’t fix this problem. I guess you would have to take apart the parent `WebPage` markup and use `itemref` there, too, so that it doesn’t include the (unrelated) item types as childs. Should probably be another question.

Comment: It still tries to get unrelated children types... I think you may be right, and it cannot be completely solved. But as it did show most of what I was asking for, I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: @unor great answer.

Comment: I could only wrap my mind around it by telling myself: when you reference an element B (with itemref) from element A, element B gains the itemscope and itemtype of the element A, and that's why the element B doesn't have it's own itemscope and itemtype.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, just don't close that div.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
  <span itemprop="name">some event</span>
  <span itemprop="startDate">2002-02-02</span>


<!-- ....zillion other HTML stuff... -->

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
      <span itemprop="distance">22 km</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

As long as the matching tag is not found, whatever is inside that initial div will still be considered part of that initial div, in that case, an Event.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use nesting of any kind (in original, much more complex project, they're in quite different sub-templates of which each one must be closed HTML structure), nor change the ordering (display reasons among other things). I've updated the question to clarify that. Also, note that your answer [won't validate](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) since ExerciseAction cannot be child od Event (only reverse is possible), and so it doesn't have itemprop required to link them together.

Comment: @MatijaNalis The only reason it didn't validate was because I copied the text you supplied in your question. The error happens because the event is set to start in the past, 2002-02-02. When updated to a future date, it works. Also, I know you have now updated your question displaying that you don't want nesting of any kind, but just to let you know, as long as the second part of data you enter for the original "Event" is not inside the "ExerciseAction" div, it will still work. For example, move the "startDate" from my answer to after the "ExerciseAction" closing div, and it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

@Guisasso is correct you just don't close the element. But on another note your not restricted to using schema just within the DIV elements and using the spans as it suggests (mere examples). If the whole page is about event related stuff and this is across the site then it might make more sense to use the body element which means your template if you have one automatically deals with opening the schema and closing. This way your articles just fill that content while the template sets it.

For example:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
   <article>
       <h1 itemprop="name">Some Event</h1>
       <span itemprop="startDate">2002-02-02</span>
       <p itemprop="description">I am the super awesome event infromation</p>
       <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
           <span itemprop="distance">22 km</span>
       </div>
   </article>
</body>
```

Or you could use it in the `MAIN` or `ARTICLE` element if you are using HTML5.

Comment: see the comment to Guisasso, your answer doesn't work for much the same reasons. I've updated the question to clarify my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I've also run to [additionalType](http://semanticweb.com/schema-org-adds-additional-type-property_b30861) property, which could be used as follows

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Event">
      <span itemprop="name">some event</span>
      <span itemprop="startDate">2002-02-02</span>


<!-- 
   ....
   zillion other HTML stuff
   ...
 -->

  <div itemprop="additionalType" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ExerciseAction">
      <span itemprop="distance">22 km</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

while that helps with my primary issue (not being able to reorder ExerciseAction/Event child-parent relationship), it does not help with other issue (not being able to nest those divs), and it is kind of kludgy (does not produce the same semantic as original working example). However, it is useful as it allows linking of schema.org itemtypes which do not have intended elements for linking, so you could link for example Book to SportsEvent or whatever.

I'm answering myself here just in case it helps someone else with similar problem, as it doesn't really help me (although it might be last-ditch resort if nothing better comes up)