# Microdata with nested product and reviews

Tags: html, microdata

I have some HTML listing reviews with HTML like:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   <img class="product-thumbnail" itemprop="image" src=...>
   <div itemscope itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
     <!-- we want this to be the Review name -->
     <h4 itemprop="name">Loved it</h4>
     ...... 
     <!-- we want this to be the Product name -->
     on <a href="/product" itemprop="name">Cool Product</a>
   </div>      
</div>
```

The problem here is that the product name is actually nested inside the review, and there is no way to distinguish it from the review title (which is also named "name").

Is there a way to solve this other than changing the HTML structure completely? For example, in made up syntax something like: `itemprop="Product:name"`or adding `itemref="../"` ?

I believe I can duplicate the product name in a `<meta>` tag but that seems less than ideal.

EDIT:
I clarified the HTML example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`itemref` attribute](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/52592/17633):

- give the element with `itemprop="name"` (in Review) an `id`
- refer to this `id` value in the `Product` via the `itemref` attribute

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="the-product">
   <img itemprop="image" src="image.png" />
   <div itemprop="review" itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">

     <h4 itemprop="name">Loved it</h4>

     <p itemprop="name" id="the-product">Cool Product</p>

   </div>      
</div>
```

While the product name is now added to the `Product` item, both names (for the review and the product) are still added to the `Review`. This is not what we want.

There are no beautiful solutions to this problem (ideally you would restructure your markup).

One solution is to create a dummy `itemscope`:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemref="the-product">
   <img itemprop="image" src="image.png" />
   <div itemprop="review" itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">

     <h4 itemprop="name">Loved it</h4>

     <div itemscope>
       <p itemprop="name" id="the-product">Cool Product</p>
     </div>

   </div>      
</div>
```

Now the product name is no longer added to the review, but now your page contains an additional item (without a type, because no `itemtype` is specified). Valid, but somewhat ugly.

(Side note: I replaced `a` with `p`, because you shouldn’t specify the `name` property on `a`: the name would be the URL, not the anchor text.)

Comment: yes, I omitted the full urls to keep the sample short, but the two name attributes are correct: one is the review name, the other the product name. I looked at itemref but it would force me to put #ids for stuff that don't need it. I will accept this as answer if nothing else comes, thanks.

Comment: @riffraff: re. the two `name`s: but this is, of course, not what you express in your markup. You say: this *review* (not the product the review is about) has two names.

Comment: well, yes, that is what the issues is about: what is the microdata markup to express that one name belongs to the review and the other belongs to the product, if such exists?

Comment: @riffraff: That is not possible without changing the nesting (i.e., moving the element to the correct item type) resp. without removing the `itemprop` attribute and adding a `meta` element to the correct item type. Every child `ìtemprop` automatically belongs to its nearest ancestor, no matter what.