# Can I use same 'itemtype' in Microdata twice?

Tags: html5, microdata, schema.org

I have an element in my website that shows the last updates of my website.

My current structure of the website is this:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/webpage"

   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar>
       <div>...some text...</div>
       <div>last update: 23/1/2014</div> //last update for whole site
   <div/>

</body>
```

The 'last update' is for the whole website, not for the sidebar!
Can I use `itemtype` twice to solve this problem?

For example, do you think this is correct?

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/webpage"

   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar>

      <div>...some text...</div>
      <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/webpage">
         <span itemscope="name">last update: </span>
         <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-01-23 13:52:00">23/1/2014</time>
      </div>
   <div/>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you [should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20245377/1591669) add several items which are about the same *thing* on the same page.

If the `datePublished` is the publication date for your whole page, it has to be nested under `WebPage` and not under `WPSideBar`.

You could use the [`itemref` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18969585/1591669) if you can’t nest it directly under `WebPage`, but you’d still have to remove it from `WPSideBar`. Unless you want this date to be associated with the `WPSideBar` *in addition*. If that’s the case, [you could use](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/55494/17633):

```html
<!-- here the 'datePublished' applies to both, the WebPage *and* the WPSideBar -->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" itemref="foobar">

   <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
     <time itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2014-01-23 13:52:00" id="foobar">23/1/2014</time>
   </div>      

</div>
```

(Note that it’s `http://schema.org/WebPage`, not `http://schema.org/webpage`.)

Comment: @Mousey: Did you meant to make this comment under OP’s question instead of my answer?

Comment: @Mousey: But this question is not about how `WPSideBar` could be referenced from `WebPage` (e.g., with the [`hasPart` property](http://schema.org/hasPart), which didn’t exist when OP asked the question).  It’s about the `datePublished` property. My code creates one (not two)`WebPage` item and one `WPSideBar` item, and both have the same `datePublished` property.

Comment: @Mousey: I agree that it’s a good practice to link the items with appropriate properties (and if the `hasPart` property would have existed back then, I’d have probably suggested it), but in my snippet the `WebPage` *has* the date (from `datePublished`) because of the `itemref` attribute.

Comment: sorry did not realized this was a full 12 months old @unor

Comment: @Mousey: No problem! And it’s always good to comment on old (as well as new) answers to note/correct/improve something. I just wanted to make sure that we’re on the same page here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same element or schema more than once, for example having multiple Products in one webpage, but in this situation you would be incorrectly marking up that TWO `WebPage` elements are on the page. Instead you need to have just one, but cope with `WPSideBar` in the middle. Based on your description `dateModified` sounds a better choice than `datePublished` too. This code uses `hasPart` to nest `WPSideBar` inside `WebPage`.

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

<div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
   <div>...some text...</div>
     <span itemscope="name">last update: </span>
     <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2014-01-23 13:52:00"/>
     <time>23/1/2014</time>       //last update for whole site
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Result from structured data tester**

```
WebPage  
hasPart [WPSideBar]:  
  dateModified: 2014-01-23T13:52:00
```

This sets the dateModified of WPSideBar only. It would be more sensible to set the date for WebPage Element only which can be done by removing this WPSideBar line from the code above and the `<span>` tag, which isn't doing anything but naming the sidebar:

```
  <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar>
```

If the two dates could be different then you can keep the line above in, and use the code

```
 <body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"><meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2014-01-20 00:00:00"/>
 <div itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPSideBar">
   <div>...some text...</div>
   <span itemscope="name">last update: </span>
   <meta itemprop="dateModified" content="2014-01-23 13:52:00"/>    
   <time>23/1/2014</time>       //last update for whole site
   </div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

**Google structured data testing result**

```
WebPage  
dateModified:   2014-01-20T13:00:00  
hasPart [WPSideBar]:  
  dateModified: 2014-01-23T13:52:00
```

**Without the *hasPart* property**

```
WebPage  
dateModified:   2014-01-20T13:00:00  

WPSideBar  
dateModified:   2014-01-23T13:52:00
```

**Explanation**
WPSideBar is a `WebPageElement`, which can be  linked to (nested inside)  the WebPage by using `itemprop="hasPart"` -  this is a property inherited from `CreativeWork`. This is **nesting of structured data.**

Your date is a non-standard format so I've used a **[Non-visible](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/policies) self-closing meta tag** to represent this date in the right format, this is one of the allowed reasons for having hidden structured data. You originally had "datetime" in place of "content".

Several syntax errors were in the original code including unclosed `<body>` tag, next time use a HTML validator/linter before creating a structured data question - it saves lots of work sorting out structured data errors that turn out not to be caused by structured data.