# Can I have duplicate Microdata properties on a single page?

Tags: microdata, schema.org

I’m trying to work with Schema.org for the first time.

Is it OK if I have duplicate `itemprop` attributes? Meaning, If I have my company phone number in different places (header, footer, sometimes in sidebar) should I tag all of them or just once? Is it a problem if I tag them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that syntaxes like Microdata and RDFa don’t *annotate* the HTML, they use the HTML just as a carrier. After parsing the Microdata/RDFa, it doesn’t matter anymore which markup was used.

If your two properties with the same content belong to the same item, it’s not useful to have the additional one, as it doesn’t add anything new (but it’s not forbidden either):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="telephone">1234</span>
  <!-- … -->
  <span itemprop="telephone">1234</span>
</div>
```

If your additional property belongs to a different item, it’s not duplicated: a different item, a different thing:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <span itemprop="telephone">1234</span>
</div>

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  <span itemprop="telephone">1234</span>
</div>
```

However, you should make sure [not to add multiple items](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/58460/17633) in a document that are about the same thing.

So if you’d have a `Person` item in the header, and a `Person` item in the footer, the problem is not that both have the same `telephone` property, but that you have two separate items in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

Search engines always hate duplicates if You have duplicate itemprop the bot must be confused to take which one for your markup result so avoid that markup once on the page

Comment: Where did you get this information?   Can you provide references or tell about your experiences that lead you to conclude this?

Answer (score -2):

As noted in this [article](http://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content), having duplicate content will result in bad SEO performance and possibly getting a page ranked so low it cannot be found by users.

A critical aspect of SEO is quality content and you cannot maintain a good organic SEO position with duplicate content.

Changing both content and HTML structure will be important to having both sites from competing with one another for SEO ratings.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That article talks about having the same text on multiple pages.   It doesn't address multiple microdata markup on  a single page.